# How to convert configuration into IOptions?

Tags: .net-core, configuration, appsettings, .net-core-2.2

I'd read a lot of articles about that but they all seem to miss the key moments, to be exact the moment of transformation of `IConfiguration` object into `TheirStronglyTypedConfiguration` object, so it looks like magic.

In my .NET Core project(NUnit test project) I have `appsettings.json`:

```
{
  "Configuration": {
    "HomePageUrl": "https://homepage.com"
  }
}
```

I load it before all tests:

```
[BeforeTestRun]
public static void LoadConfiguration()
{
    IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                            .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                            .Build();
}
```

**Question:** but how to transform it into strongly typed object that would have the string property `HomePageUrl`?

EDIT:

I try that:

```
IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                    .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                                    .Build();
            config.GetSection("").Bind
```

but I have no `Bind` method.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax for model binding has changed from RC1 to RC2.

You need to bind a settings class to your configuration you need in ConfigureServices method of Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<MySettings>(options => Configuration.GetSection("MySettings").Bind(options));
}
```

Comment: I know that I can do it, the question is about strongly typed `IOptions`.

Comment: Excuse me for misunderstanding. see the updated answer.